# Gitlab Changelog API: Writing CHANGELOG that works with GitLab Pages

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, changelog, mkdocs, gitlab-pages

The [GitLab Changelog API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#add-changelog-data-to-a-changelog-file) amends CHANGELOG.md with commit title and merge request information. However, it does it in a way to only work within GitLab UI (i.e., `project-name@long-hash`). My use case is to also publish the CHANGELOG.md using mkdocs through the GitLab CI/CD. Thus, having an absolute URL to each commit and merge request is what I need. By default, the Changelog API does not do this.

It generates something like this:

```
[Commit message](group/repo@abcdef123456hash).
```

What I would like is something like:

```
[Commit message](https://gitlab.com/group/repo/-/commit/abcdef123456hash).
```

For merge requests, it does:

```
group@repo!42
```

Desire is:

```
https://gitlab.com/group/repo/-/merge_requests/42
```

The [template_data](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#template-data) mentions several variables but there's no way to get an absolute URL it seems.

For reference, my `changelog_config.yml` `template` is:

```yaml
template: |
  {% if categories %}
  {% each categories %}
  ### {{ title }} ({% if single_change %}1 change{% else %}{{ count }} changes{% end %})

  {% each entries %}
  - [{{ title }}]({{ commit.reference }})\
  {% if author.credit %} by {{ author.reference }}{% end %}\
  {% if commit.trailers.MR %}\
   ([merge request]({{ commit.trailers.MR }}))\
  {% else %}\
  {% if merge_request %}\
   ([merge request]({{ merge_request.reference }}))\
  {% end %}\
  {% end %}

  {% end %}

  {% end %}
  {% else %}
  No changes.
  {% end %}
```

Comment: We're in the same boat here. Really struggling to work with these templates/data. @astrochun, we're you ever able to make any progress on this? Thanks!

Comment: @bnjmn, no I haven't found a solution yet though I haven't put much effort.